# How can I get an XmlNode from a DataSet?

Tags: asp.net, xml, dataset, xmldocument, xmlwriter

I'm trying to write an XML document using an `XmlWriter` and an `XmlDocument`.  I have 4 child nodes to write in the root element, and the first three worked out fine.  The last one, however, is being generated from a `DataSet`.  Here is my abbreviated code:

```
DataSetds; 

XmlNode RecordSet = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "RecordSet", "");
XmlNode RecordSetTotal = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Attribute, "TOTAL", "");
RecordSetTotal.Value = gvExcelData.Rows.Count.ToString();
RecordSet.Attributes.SetNamedItem(RecordSetTotal);
RecordSet.InnerXml = ds.GetXml();
root.AppendChild(RecordSet);
```

Which outputs the XML:

```
<RecordSet TOTAL="2">
    <RecordSet>
        <Record>
            <Column 1></Column 1>
            <Column 2></Column 2>
            <Column 3></Column 3>
            <Column 4></Column 4>
            <Column 5></Column 5>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <Column 1></Column 1>
            <Column 2></Column 2>
            <Column 3></Column 3>
            <Column 4></Column 4>
            <Column 5></Column 5>
        </Record>
    </RecordSet>
</RecordSet>
```

I need only one root element `RecordSet` and it needs to have an attribute `Total` equal to the total number of records. If somehow I could parse the XML string I get from `ds.GetXml()` into an `XmlNode` directly, I could then set my attributes and be on my way.  But I could be wrong.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing exactly that. Load it into an XmlDocument, process it, copy it over.

Comment: No example? This question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873967/reading-sql-to-dataset-to-xmldocument