# Reading SQL to DataSet to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

The code below works dreamy. But can it be made more compact and C#'ish? Especially i have suspicions regarding two issues.

1. Isn't it ugly (old C-style) filling `fill` a variable by using it as a in-parameter?
2. Can the code be made more compact instead of going through a `String`?

C#

```
String
  connectionString = "...",
  sqlStatement = "select * from Test",
  output = "";

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, connectionString);
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Contents");
adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Test");
StringWriter stringWriter=new StringWriter();
dataSet.WriteXml(new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter));
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
output = stringWriter.ToString();
document.LoadXml(output);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about making it more C#ish or compact, but you do need to close your Adapter and StringWriter. I would use the `using` block.

```
   String
       connectionString = "...",
       sqlStatement = "select * from Test",
       output = "";

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Contents");
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, connectionString)){
        adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Test");}
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) { 
      dataSet.WriteXml(new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter));
      output = stringWriter.ToString();
    };
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(output);
```

Comment: Aren't they automatically closed when they go out of the scope?

Comment: Oddly enough, they don't.  From MSDN: If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it remains open. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose. Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent...

To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

Comment: Now, that i think about it, i've read that before too. But with time passing by i forgot... Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was missing the XmlTextWriter casting, got a big pile of XML as a value in the first node. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Although Holger's answer is really good, I was actually working with Linq to XML. What I leveraged from his code into Linq is even more elegant, I think, if your output is an XElement instead of an XmlDocument or an XmlNode. You also don't need to cast to XmlTextWriter.

```
String
   strConnection = "...",
   strSQL = "select * from Test",

XElement objOutput = null;

DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet("output");

using (SqlDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strConnection)){
    objAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "row");}
using (StringWriter objWriter = new StringWriter()) { 
  objDataSet.WriteXml(objWriter);
  XDocument objDoc = XDocument.Parse(objDataSet.GetXml());
  objOutput = objDoc.Root;
};
return objOutput;
```