# XMl File embeded in SQL to C# Program

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I am making a program in C# that will read data from a SQL database. The data is stored in a XML file within the SQL Database. The column is a XML data type.

Is there a way to import the XML document from SQL to the C# program? I need it as a XML file because the program will go through the nodes and adjust data, overwrite it, and re-enter it into the Database.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Visual Studio 2010 is the IDE for the C#.

Comment: Not totally sure what you are asking. If you are trying to transform the xml into data that can be edited you can use a DataSet and it wil generate the DataTable collection dynamically based on your xml. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: don't be lazy, next time try to google a little bit first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873967/reading-sql-to-dataset-to-xmldocument

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve it as an `XDocument` [easily enough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();

if (reader.MoveToContent() != XmlNodeType.None)
{
    return XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can retrieve it as a Stream or String, you can just do: `var doc = XDocument.Load(source)`.

For example:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select XmlColumn from Table", connection))
{
connection.Open();  
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reader["XmlColumn"].ToString());
        // do sth with xml:
        var id = xmlDoc.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.Equals("Ping")).Select(e => e.Attribute("id").Value);
    }
}
}
```